# Can I fix this without using responsive?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, responsive, card

I use the card element in Bootstrap, and whenever I zoom in, the heights between these 3 cards are different (because of the card title). How can I fix that, and can I do it without using responsive technique @media?

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
          <div class="card">
            <img src="img/card-img.png" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Massage Therapy</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Living winged said you darkness you're divide gathered and bring one seasons face great dr Waters firmamen: place which.</p>
              <button class="btn btn-hover">read more</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        // I have to make the code section smaller, but 2 other cards are the same as the first one above
      </div>
```

and CSS:

```
.content > .container .row .card {
    padding: 1.9rem;
}

.content > .container .row .card > .card-body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    padding-top: 0;
    position: relative;
}

.content > .container .row .card > .card-body > h5 {
    font-size: 2.3rem;
    margin: 4.2rem 0 2.9rem 0;
}

.content > .container .row .card > .card-body > p {
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    margin-bottom: 4.5rem;
    line-height: 2.6rem;
}

.content > .container .row .card > .card-body > button {
    width: 14rem;
    height: 4.4rem;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
}
```

[Normal size:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAIpO.png)

[Zoom in:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbJcZ.png)

Thank you and have a good day!

Comment: thank you guys for the solutions. After asking this, I also figured out one more solution for this, is to use CSS text-overflow property. Again, thank you so much for the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.cols` are all the same height so you can stretch your cards to all be 100% of the column so they'll always stay the same height regardless of content or zoom.

```
.content > .container .row .card {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 1.9rem;
}
```

```css
.content > .container .row .card {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 1.9rem;
}

.content > .container .row .card > .card-body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    padding-top: 0;
    position: relative;
}

.content > .container .row .card > .card-body > h5 {
    font-size: 2.3rem;
    margin: 4.2rem 0 2.9rem 0;
}

.content > .container .row .card > .card-body > p {
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    margin-bottom: 4.5rem;
    line-height: 2.6rem;
}

.content > .container .row .card > .card-body > button {
    width: 14rem;
    height: 4.4rem;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="content">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
          <div class="card">
            <img src="img/card-img.png" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Massage Therapy</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Living winged said you darkness you're divide gathered and bring one seasons face great dr Waters firmamen: place which.</p>
              <button class="btn btn-hover">read more</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
          <div class="card">
            <img src="img/card-img.png" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Massage Therapy With More Words</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Living winged said you darkness you're divide gathered and bring one seasons face great dr Waters firmamen: place which.</p>
              <button class="btn btn-hover">read more</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">
          <div class="card">
            <img src="img/card-img.png" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Massage Therapy with Even More Words</h5>
              <p class="card-text">Living winged said you darkness you're divide gathered and bring one seasons face great dr Waters firmamen: place which.</p>
              <button class="btn btn-hover">read more</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may inbricate flex boxes and help yourself with Bootstrap 4 classes :

possible example to run fullpage to test behavior

```css
/* here comes your custom css missing in bootstrap */
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/><div class="row">

  <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 d-flex flex-column">
    <div class="card flex-grow-1 d-flex flex-column" >
      <img src="http://dummyimage.com/200x50" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
      <div class="card-body flex-grow-1 d-flex flex-column ">
        <h5 class="card-title mx-auto">Massage <br>Therapy</h5>
        <p class="card-text mx-auto">Living winged said you darkness you're divide gathered and bring one seasons face great dr Waters firmamen: place which.</p>
        <button class="btn btn-hover alert alert-info mx-auto">read more</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 d-flex flex-column">
    <div class="card flex-grow-1 d-flex flex-column">
      <img src="http://dummyimage.com/200x50" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
      <div class="card-body flex-grow-1 d-flex flex-column ">
        <h5 class="card-title mx-auto">Massage Therapy</h5>
        <p class="card-text my-auto">Living winged .</p>
        <button class="btn btn-hover alert alert-info mx-auto">read more</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 d-flex flex-column">
    <div class="card flex-grow-1 d-flex flex-column">
      <img src="http://dummyimage.com/200x50" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
      <div class="card-body flex-grow-1 d-flex flex-column ">
        <h5 class="card-title mx-auto">Massage </h5>
        <p class="card-text my-auto">Living winged said you darkness you're divide gathered and bring one seasons face great dr Waters firmamen: place which.</p>
        <button class="btn btn-hover alert alert-info mx-auto">read more</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/display/  &  https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/spacing/